# How do I deploy a SharePoint Add-In .app file to a non-Office 365 SharePoint Site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, napa

I am just getting started with SharePoint Add-Ins in 2013. My background is in on-Premise development, or server-side development. I have one Office 365 site, and several SharePoint Hosted sites with Apps4Rent. I have built a couple of demo Apps (or Add-Ins, as they are now called) using Napa, and I want to deploy them to my hosted sites. The only option I see is to deploy it to the SharePoint App Store. Is there any way to just download the apps, and upload it to my Solutions gallery? What is the best way to go about this?

UPDATE: Progress! I figured out that I had to Publish my App from Napa, now I can download it as an .app file to my hard drive. Now I need to convert it to a .wsp so my other site will recognize it. So, how do I convert an .app file to a .wsp file?

UPDATE AGAIN: I am really grasping at straws here. I do not KNOW the best way to proceed, that is why I am asking for help. What I have determined so far is that I can use an App Catalog if I was copying from one Office 365 site to another. But the destination site is not an Office 365 site. I cannot create an App Catalog there. So I see no way to deploy an .app file. That is why I think I need a .wsp file to deploy it to the Solutions gallery. But I am very much open to any OTHER suggestion as to how to proceed.

Comment: Why not use the app? Microsoft recommends apps over sandboxed solutions (which should be restricted to NCSS): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163114.aspx#AppWhenYouCan

Comment: I want to use the app. But I don't know how to deploy it to a non-Office 365 SharePoint site. That is what I need help with.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint-apps.html), you can set up an app catalog.  Once you have one set up, add the .app file to the catalog, and then you can add the app to any site.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add your add-ins into your on premises sites then you can create a App catalog site and add these downloaded apps into this , from app catalog you can add to your on premises hosted sites.

Comment: There is no on-premise site. I have an Office 365 hosted site, and several third-party hosted sites using Apps4Rent.

Comment: How do I DOWNLOAD the app I created in the first place?

Comment: Yes , you can create a app catalog site for the office 365 environment and you can upload the apps there . please refer https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-App-Catalog-to-make-custom-business-apps-available-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-0b6ab336-8b83-423f-a06b-bcc52861cba0

Comment: You miss my point. How do I DOWNLOAD an App I have created?

Comment: you can open the app in visual studio from where you can package the app and upload it into the app catlog . https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonz/2012/07/17/introducing-napa-office-365-development-tools/

Comment: Oh, so if I create an App Catalog, I can deploy my Napa apps to the App Catalog, and then download them? Is that correct?

Comment: OK, I see where I can UPLOAD an Add In to the App Catalog, how do I copy an app built with Napa (not with Visual Studio) to this App Catalog?

Comment: first you need to open the app from napa with visual studio and then from visual studio you can publish this app you'll get an app file this app file you can upload to the App catalog , from there you can add it to the sites

Comment: My non-Office 365 sites do not allow me to create an App Catalog. If I could, that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

For downloading APP build from Napa, follow below steps.

you need to open the APP in napa application...

Below is sample url

https://www.napacloudapp.com/Projects/Edit/guid/Pages/yourpage.aspx

From left panel, Use publish option(2nd last option)

This will allow you to publish this app to App Packages library.

https://yourdomain/sites/yoursite/Lists/AppPackages/Forms/AllItems.aspx

here you will find your yourfirstapp.app which you can download and proceed further...

I don't think we can just convert APP file to WSP solution, we need to rebuild solution by using code in app.

**Convert APP to WSP solution**

*Here below are the steps for that:

Create Empty SharePoint Solution in Visual Studio.

Choose SharePoint sandbox solution in that.

Create one visual webpart from add new item.

Find the JavaScript code from the SharePoint app code.

Add that code in the visual webpart or attach JS file in that webpart.

Add related HTML code in the visual webpart.

Do rebuild and deploy the solution.*

Comment: Thanks, I was able to download it, but the Solutions Gallery is expecting a .wsp file. So I need to convert my .app to a .wsp. I have updated my original question.

Comment: why do you want to convert to wsp ? it is SP 2010 version ? I don't think it can be converted to WSP directly but you have to do it manually..... Edited answer accordingly..

Comment: I want to build apps for my SharePoint Foundation 2013 sites. They are not hosted by Office 365. I want to build apps in Office 365 and copy them over, I have no idea how I am supposed to do that. I don't want to go through the App Store just to deploy my own apps.

Comment: I have edited answer on how to convert APP to WSP...

Comment: Thank you, you asked why I want to do that. If there is a BETTER way to copy an Add-In to a SharePoint Hosted site, instead of publishing to the App Store, then tell me that instead.